# Batch find text in file and replace with other text

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I need to use Batch to check file Directory.twml to see if it contains any words from file blocked.twml and if it does replace with [Blocked]

Here is an example of both files:

Directory.twml

```
11:38:38.90 [System] Twml Has joined the chat.
11:38:41.17 [User]   Twml says: line one
11:38:42.96 [User]   Twml says: line bad two
11:38:46.27 [User]   Twml says: line three
11:38:50.16 [User]   Twml says: you get the idea here
11:38:52.35 [System] Twml Has logged off.
```

Blocked.twml

```
word1
word2
word3
bad
word5
word6
```

What i want Directory.twml to say look like is

```
11:38:38.90 [System] Twml Has joined the chat.
11:38:41.17 [User]   Twml says: line one
11:38:42.96 [User]   Twml says: line [Blocked] two
11:38:46.27 [User]   Twml says: line three
11:38:50.16 [User]   Twml says: you get the idea here
11:38:52.35 [System] Twml Has logged off.
```

I already can use Findstr to look in the file and see if the text exists but thats as far as i can get, I need to not check for a set word but check the list of words in the file Blocked.twml

```
findstr /i "bad" <"Directory.twml" 1>nul
```

Also i can remove the word from the file but i want to replace it not just remove

```
findstr /i /v /c:"%text%" Directory.twml > "Directory.twmll" 2>nul 
del Directory.twml /s /a >nul
copy Directory.twmll Directory.twml >nul
attrib +h Directory.twml
del Directory.twmll /s /a >nul
```

But again this is a set text to look for not from what is in a file as a list

If Directory.twml contains anything in Blocked.twml replace with [Blocked] but i cant figure out how to do it

========= Edit ===========

This is the solution:

```
(
for /f "delims=" %%A in (Directory.twml) do (
set "line=%%A"
for /f "delims=" %%B in (blocked.twml) do set "line=!line: %%B = [Blocked] !"
echo !line!
)
)>Directory.new
```

Its output looked like this for me

```
13:22:14.16 [User]   twml says: this is a test
13:22:20.37 [User]   twml says: this is a [Blocked] word test
```

Comment: This is not a teaching comment it is a request; Please accept @Stephan's answer because your post clearly indicates that you have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read Directory.twml line by line. For each line, read blocked.twml and replace each word with the string `[Blocked]`. Echo the changed line. Redirect the whole output to a new file:

```
@echo off 
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
(
  for /f "delims=" %%A in (Directory.twml) do (
    set "line=%%A"
    for /f "delims=" %%B in (blocked.twml) do set "line=!line:%%B=[Blocked]!"
    echo !line!
  )
)>Directory.new
```

I'll leave it to you to rename the new file to the original name.

Note: something like `abadad` will be changed to `a[Blocked]ad`. You could change `set "line=!line:%%B=[Blocked]!"` to `set "line=!line: %%B = [Blocked] !"` to catch word boundaries, but then `This is bad, I think.` wouldn't be changed.

Note: a single`!` will be removed. If there are more than one `!` in a line, text between them will disappear. Batch isn't really a good choice to do such things...

Comment: that worked thank you exactly what i needed, and i know its probably not the best way but im limited to just using batch here for this. it works exactly as it should though. updated my question to include it

Comment: I see what you mean though about replacing middle of words, the filter file i have from google has hell in it to hello replaces to [Blocked]o

Answer (score 0):

1. Simply 1 command line, using `msr.exe` to replace text in `Directory.twml` **if it's replaceable**:

`for /f "tokens=*" %a in (Blocked.twml) do @msr -p Directory.twml -i -x "%a" -o "[Blocked]" -R`

- Safer way if `Blocked.twml` has whitespace lines and escape them:

  `for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('msr -p Blocked.twml -t "\w+" -PAC') do @msr -p Directory.twml -i -x "%a" -o "[Blocked]" -R`

  Result like:
  [image: Replace-file-method]

2.If `Directory.twml` shouldn't be replaced, use following methods according to your purposes like:

- You can copy `Directory.twml` to a tmp file and use that tmp file in the above command.
- If you want just to display the replaced line, without replacing file:

  - Use `-O` to just show matched/replaced command result:

  `for /f "tokens=*" %a in (Blocked.twml) do @msr -p Directory.twml -x "%a" -o "[Blocked]" -O`

  - Use `-O -P -A` to show pure replaced result: (add `-C` if you don't want color)

  `for /f "tokens=*" %a in (Blocked.twml) do @msr -p Directory.twml -x "%a" -o "[Blocked]" -OPA`

  Result like:
  [image: just-replace-text-not-file]
  `msr.exe` / `msr.gcc*` is a single and portable exe tool about 1.6MB without dependencies and with cross platform versions, to find and replace file text with color and summary info and backup support, etc. see my open project https://github.com/qualiu/msr (`tools` directory), docs like usage, performance comparison with **findstr** and **grep**; built-in doc like: https://qualiu.github.io/msr/usage-by-running/msr-Windows.html